# VMware Player / VMware Workstation installation in KALI

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, kali-linux

I have been trying to get VMWare Player/ VMWare workstation installed in KALI Linux for almost ages now. I might look a little exaggerating but I would like to quote it that way to bring about the level of frustration now that I have reached to :

> **I have tried almost every possible relevant link and the solution mentioned there in to have my problem solved and finally get either VMWare Player/Worskstation working, but have found only more frustration instead of any success.**

My system specifications and things I have already tried out :

- My OS is 32-bit KALI Linux kernel 1.1.0(lsb_release -a on my system gives :
   **No LSB modules are available.

  Distributor ID: Kali

  Description:    Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0

  Release:    1.1.0

  Codename:   moto**
- uname -r on my system is : **3.18.0-kali1-686-pae**
- VMWare Player version I have is **VMware-Player-5.0.4-1945795.i386.bundle**
- VMWare Worksatation version I have is **VMware-Workstation-Full-7.1.4-385536.i386.bundle**
- I have already run apt-get update umpteen number of times.
- I have already done apt-get install build-essential and now if I do it again the output is : 
  **Reading package lists... Done

  Building dependency tree

  Reading state information... Done

  build-essential is already the newest version.**
- As suggested in some places, I have already tried apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-686-pae and I get the output as the same as above, stating that it is already the newest version.
- As suggested in some places, I have also tried this with some minor changes depending on my directory structures:
  **cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux

  sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h

  sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h

  sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h**
  So currently doing a 
  /lib/modules/3.18.0-kali1-686-pae/build/include# ls -la 
   shows that I have the required symlinks, (the below is the symlinks I now have) 
  autoconf.h -> ./generated/autoconf.h
  utsrelease.h -> ./generated/utsrelease.h
  version.h -> ./generated/uapi/linux/version.h
- I have rebooted my system after each of these updates.

I need some desperate help here. Is there any thing else that needs to be done to get VMWare Player/Workstation working on my system ? As of now if I run either of them I get the below :

Unable to start services.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-8692.log for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `3.18.0-kali1-amd64`. I also had a problem with `vmware-player 6.x`. Uninstalling 6.0.x and installing 7.0 fixed the issues for me.

```
vmware-installer -l

sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-player

sudo ./VMware-Player-7.0.0-2305329.x86_64.bundle
```

I think the recent update to kernel 3.18 is just incompatible with version 6 or less.
About workstation I am not sure, since I just use the player.

Comment: am afraid.. this did not solve the problem either.